# Проверка на существование пользователя в бд

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Подскажите как можно проверить, есть ли в бд пользователь с таким именем и паролем или нет. используется СУБД MSSQL. Другими словами мне нужно именно аутентифицироваться на сайте.

моя строка подключения **ConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"**

```
public bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: выполнить select по таблице пользователей с фильтром по логину и паролю, если найдется юзер - то он есть в БД, не найдется - нет в БД

Comment: @tym32167, у меня не хранится пароль в таблице

Comment: а как у вас юзеры логинятся на сайт?

Comment: @tym32167, используется СУБД MSSQL, пароли зашиты в учетке пользователя на сервере..

Comment: Наверное попытаться законектиться с указанным user-ом и паролем :). Если получиться, то он там есть :). Если бы я проектировал сервер, то первое о чем бы я подумал, так это о том как защитить систему от подобного сканирования.

Comment: `пароли зашиты в учетке пользователя на сервере` вы же туда SQL звпрос и пишете

Comment: а зачем Вам проверка на существование пользователя?

Comment: @Bald, я только изучаю c#. Возможно и не надо. Но логика такая, если введенные в форму данные проходят проверку, то пускать дальше на главную страницу иначе говорить "ты кто такой, давай досвидания".

Comment: у Вас в бд хранится только логин пользователя? если да то сделайте запрос вида `select * from users where login = user_name`, и проверьте что вернет сервер, где user_name это login пользователя, как выполнить запрос и как в него передать параметр для фильтрации это другой большой вопрос. свое знакомство с [tag:C#] я начинал вот с этого [ресурса](https://metanit.com/sharp/)

Comment: @Bald, спасибо за ваш комментарий. Я сейчас как раз и читаю данный ресурс(про dapper). Передать параметр не проблема, но понять как авторизоваться на сайте, не понимаю. Мне нужно именно авторизоваться.

Comment: нет, вам надо аутентифицироваться, то есть пройти проверку на логин/пароль, авторизация - это уже про роли юзера.

Comment: @tym32167, да вы правы, именно так.

Comment: Ну во-первых, нужно всё-таки решить, что за задачу решаем: нам нужно войти этим пользователем или поискать есть ли такой пользователь. Во-вторых, нужно понимать, что если вы даже проверили существование логина на sql server, то вообще не факт, что этому пользователю даны права на доступ к базе (через роли сервера типа sysadmin :) , через сопоставление с пользователем этой базы) В-третьих, непонятно, что мешает использовать механизм asp.net core identity, который включается парой нажатий мышкой в проекте?

Comment: @AK, нужно проверить коннект к БД с такими учетными данными, вы правы проверять существование логина нет смысла. asp.net core Identity читал, искал примеры, но все они слишком громоздкие, если у вас есть пример простяцкий на аутентификацию дайте взглянуть, буду благодарен.